# How do I recalculate in Excel for Mac?

Tags: microsoft

This is driving me a little bit crazy. In my old PC days I used to press either <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F9</kbd> (I can't remember) to have Excel `recalculate`.

What is the Mac equivalent?

PS: Perhaps this is not the place to ask. If so, please redirect me. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK it's <kbd>F9</kbd> on Windows .

So did you try the keystrokes <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> ?

Comment: Learning something new everyday feels always great :)

Answer (score 8):

To recalc in Mac:

**Command** + **=**

You can try also changing Excel preferences:
Command  ,
Calculation
"Manually" radio button

Comment: For some reason fn + f9 does not work for me. CMD + = does work, however.

Answer (score 3):

fn + f9 works if you disable mission control shortcut (it is defined as F9 by default)

[image]